# Python Button Bind two functions and send arguments with the binding

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter, bind

I am somewhat new to python still, and am working on a project including a GUI. I using with Tkinter and buttons a lot, and am curious if there was a way to run a function with a bind because I want one thing to happen when it is presses and something else when it is released.

```
        s = str(x+1) + ":" + str(y+1)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('button.png'))
        b = Tkinter.Button(field_hid, image=img, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, background='grey')
        b.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda s=s, button=b: location_down(event,s,button))
        b.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda s=s, button=b: location_up(event,s,button))
        b.img = img
        b.pack()
        b.grid(row=x, column=y)
```

I don't understand how I am to do this, as the only thing that can be passed to the function is the event, but my program requires the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to use bind is to have it call a function. When you use `lambda` you are just creating an anonymous function. You can easily do:

```
b.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.SomeOtherFunction)
```

`lambda` is useful when you want to pass additional arguments to the function. Unlike when using the `command` option, with bindings you get an event object with lots of useful information so you may not need to pass any additional information.

For example, you could do this:

```
def OnPress(event):
    print "widget %s was pressed" % event.widget
def OnRelease(event):
    print "widget %s was released" % event.widget

b = Button(...)
b.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", OnPress)
b.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", OnRelease)
```

For a good introduction to binding see [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) on effbot.org.

Comment: Thank you, lambdas were very interesting